# For some reason there is a line in the middle of my model

Tags: mirror-modifier

[image]

I think the line might be be because I used the mirror modifier...

EDIT: Picture with modifiers

Comment: Please provide an image of your modifier stack as well as your object in edit mode. There can be a few different reasons why the line is appearing and more details will be needed to understand the cause.

Comment: You may have an internal face. Uncheck the monitor icon on the modifier panel and see if there's a face there. If so, delete it.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This will be the Mirror modifier .. check for internal faces on the mirror plane?